# problem with train function neural networks in matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have a problem with train function

??? Error using ==> network.train
Targets are incorrectly sized for network.
Matrix must have 2 columns.
Error in ==> tfarst1 at 14
[net,tr]=train(net,min_max,f);

```
>> whos
Name          Size                    Bytes  Class
Fs            1x1                         8  double array
d         22050x1                    176400  double array
f             1x432                    3456  double array
h             1x1                         8  double array
h1            1x1                         8  double array
m           432x12                    41472  double array
min_max     432x2                      6912  double array
net           1x1                     85013  network object
s         55512x1                    888192  double array (complex)
Grand total is 92380 elements using 1201469 bytes
```

I only have one output for each row how can I fix it?and this is my code

```
clear;clc
Fs=11025;
d=wavread('alhai.wav');
s=specgram(d,512,Fs,kaiser(500,5),400);
s=s(:);
m=melcepst(s,Fs);
min_max=minmax(m);
[h h1] = size(m);
f=ones(1,h);
net=newff(min_max,[5 1],{'tansig','purelin'},'trainlm');
net.trainParam.show=500;
net.trainParam.goal=1e-5;
net.trainParam.epochs=5000;
[net,tr]=train(net,min_max,f);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my assertion below was correct.  I don't have a copy of Matlab to check it out on.  Check to make sure all of your dimensions match up the ones given [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/train.html).  It may be incorrect for you to use min_max in both places, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

You have basically already answered your own question. The command cannot run because you don't provide it with the correct inputs as specified when you type `help train`.

In case more input is required than you actually have, you can of course try to feed the function some dummy input. However, without deep understanding of how `train` works this is likely to yield undesirable results.